# How can I reference a has-many-through relationship in a Linq where clause?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have classes:

- ComponentType

  - id
  - Name
  - ...
- Component

  - Id
  - ComponentTypeID
  - ...
- RigAction

  - id
  - RigActionTypeID (pointing to RigActionType below)
  - ComponentID (pointing to component above)
- RigActionType

  - Name
  - ...

I am attempting to query all `RigActions` using a `RigActionTypeID` and a `ComponentTypeID` and am struggling with Linq's `where()` method. I figured out the first portion in the code below, but am having trouble checking the componentTypeID property in the second portion.

```
var actions = db.RigActions
    .Where(ra => ra.RigActionTypeID == rigActionTypeID)
    .Where(ra => ra.Components.SelectMany(c => c.ComponentTypeID == componentTypeID));
```

Comment: Do you need the SelectMany?  How about:var actions = db.RigActions.Where(ra => ra.RigActionTypeID == rigActionTypeID).Where(ra => ra.Components.ComponentTypeID == componentTypeID));

Comment: @MikeH I may just have this defined wrong, but in this instance `ra.Components` is an EntitySet - so calling `.ComponentTypeID` would be calling it on the set, not the entity. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Is the code you posted compiling?  The SelectMany doesn't seem like it should work.

Comment: `SelectMany` would yield Boolean results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectMany` flattens enumerations of enumerations. If the purpose of your LINQ query is to yield components of a specific type then this should do it:

```
var components = db.RigActions
    .Where(ra => ra.RigActionTypeID == rigActionTypeID)
    .SelectMany(
        ra => ra.Components
            .Where(c => c.ComponentTypeID == componentTypeID)
    );
```

---

If, however, you intend to return actions having at least one component of a specific type, then do this:

```
var actions = db.RigActions
    .Where(ra => ra.RigActionTypeID == rigActionTypeID &&
                 ra.Components.Any(c => c.ComponentTypeID == componentTypeID)
    );
```

If you need actions having only components of a specific type do:

```
var actions = db.RigActions
    .Where(ra => ra.RigActionTypeID == rigActionTypeID &&
                 ra.Components.All(c => c.ComponentTypeID == componentTypeID)
    );
```

---

If you need to select actions and keep only some of the components inside of the actions at the same time, then do this (assuming that `Components` is a `List<>` that is not readonly):

```
var actions = db.RigActions
    .Where(ra => ra.RigActionTypeID == rigActionTypeID)
    .Select( ra => {
        ra.Components = ra.Components
            .Where(c => c.ComponentTypeID == componentTypeID)
            .ToList();
        return ra;
    });
```

If the list is readonly do this:

```
var actions = db.RigActions
    .Where(ra => ra.RigActionTypeID == rigActionTypeID)
    .Select( ra => {
        ra.Components.RemoveAll(c => c.ComponentTypeID != componentTypeID);
        return ra;
    });
```

If you are not allowed to change the original components collection then you will have to create new RigActions having new, filtered components lists.

Answer (score 1):

This will find `RigActions` matching `rigActionTypeID` and that have at least one `component` with the given `componentTypeID`

```
var actions = db.RigActions.Where(ra => ra.RigActionTypeID == rigActionTypeID
                && ra.Components.Any(c => c.ComponentTypeID == componentTypeID));
```

Comment: Nailed it. I ended up marking Olivier as the accepted answer though due to his completeness.